# Show that a Fibonacci sequence is a linear combination of these two sequences...

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, fibonacci-numbers

Let $K$ denote the set of all Fibonacci sequences. Show that each Kth sequence is a linear combination of other sequences.

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: What did you try? Where do you get stuck?

Comment: Perhaps you should define what is meant by "Fibonacci sequences" here, so that we know what $K$ actually is.

Answer (score 1):

Let $k_0=A_0$ and $k_1=B_0$ then $k_n= A_0 j_{2,n} + B_0 j_{1,n}$. (Where $j_{1,n}$ denotes the $n^{th}$ term in the $j_1$ sequence (with the indexing starting at $0$)).